# Upsell : get parent product from child product id

Tags: magento

i am looking for code which can help me get parent product id from child product Id and this both products are related using upsell feature

so far i was able to retrieve child products id from parent id by using below code

```
   //Get product detail using product id  (Suppose you have product id is : $product_id)
   $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

   // Fetch list of upsell product using query.
   $upsell_product = $_product->getUpSellProductCollection();
```

but i want result in reverse manner

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: means you are asking about configurable product?

Comment: @KeyurShah no dude, i am talking about Upsell product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$childProductId = 17;//edit this value, or get it by $product->getId()
$productsLinkedAsUpsell = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_link')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('linked_product_id', $childProductId)
        ->addFieldToFilter('link_type_id', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Link::LINK_TYPE_UPSELL);
foreach ($productsLinkedAsUpsell as $upsell) {
    $parentId = $upsell->getProductId();
}
```